# How do I write articles without infringing on OSS project's logos and brands?

Tags: tv, media

I am sorry if this is not the place where to ask and if so, I would appreciate any of the moderators move this question to the right place in order to get the proper answer.

I am the webmaster and IT consultant for several local media, radio and TV stations and newspapers at my Place in Mexico. Let's mention the TV Channel 9 (http://www.canal9tampico.com), Diario Debate (http://www.diariodebate.info), El Universo Tamaulipeco Noticias (http://eluniversotamaulipeco.com)

Some of them have invited me to write a coverage or editorial column about technology and I am very interested on writing about Ubuntu and Open Source software such as The GIMP, InkScape, LibreOffice, etc.

The coverage will -of course- include my personal achievements and experiences based on the day-to-day usage of these software, among other software and/or online services.

I would like to know if it is legal or at least I won't break any rules by to mention the brand names, use logos to illustrate or including screenshots, video tutorials or something in the writing.

I will appreciate a lot your feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.** But to the best of my knowledge, what you're describing is permitted by every country's trademark laws, regardless of the wishes of the trademark holders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I sent an email to Canonical, and after a couple of days I received an answer which I place here in order to give this question as answered and to keep a record for future reference.

> Hi Geppettvs
>
> Thanks for getting in touch.
>
> *I have opened this question in AskUbuntu ([How do I write articles without infringing on OSS project's logos and brands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272398/how-do-i-write-articles-without-infringing-on-oss-projects-logos-and-brands)) with no answers yet. So I found this place and dare to ask. I am the
>   webmaster and IT consultant for several local media, radio and TV
>   stations and newspapers at my Place in Mexico. Let's mention the TV
>   Channel 9 (http://www.canal9tampico.com), Diario Debate
>   (http://www.diariodebate.info), El Universo Tamaulipeco Noticias
>   (http://eluniversotamaulipeco.com) Some of them have invited me to
>   write a coverage or editorial column about technology and I am very
>   interested on writing about Ubuntu and Open Source software such as
>   The GIMP, InkScape, LibreOffice, etc. The coverage will -of course-
>   include my personal achievements and experiences based on the
>   day-to-day usage of these software, among other software and/or online
>   services. I would like to know if it is legal or at least I won't
>   break any rules by to mention the brand names, use logos to illustrate
>   or including screenshots, video tutorials or something in the writing.
>   I will appreciate a lot your feedback. Thanks in advance.*
>
> We are really pleased to hear your interest in writing about Ubuntu.
>   Whilst we can appreciate the passion Ubuntu inspires, we also have to
>   be diligent to ensure that the trademarks are used correctly.
>
> To keep the balance between the integrity of our trademarks and the
>   ability to customise Ubuntu, we’ve tried to define a reasonable
>   trademark policy that allows our Community to use Ubuntu and to
>   promote the project. You can read the full policy at
>   http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy.
>
> As you can see from our policy using the trademarks in your
>   discussion, commentary, criticism or parody, in ways that
>   unequivocally do not imply endorsement, is permissible. You are free
>   to write articles, create websites, blog about, or talk about Ubuntu -
>   as long as it's clear to everyone (including people completely
>   unfamiliar with Ubuntu) that you are simply referring to Ubuntu and in
>   no way speaking for Canonical or the Ubuntu project.
>
> So as long as you do not imply that you are affiliated with Canonical
>   or Ubuntu, please go ahead!
>
> Good luck with your writing!
>
> Thanks,
>
> Isabel

After reading the Trademark Policy Document, I find quite interesting the words that refers to:

> ## Commentary and parody
>
> The Ubuntu trademarks are designed to cover use of a mark to imply origin or endorsement by the project. When a user downloads something
>   called Ubuntu, they should know it comes from the Ubuntu project. This
>   helps Ubuntu build a reputation that will not be damaged by confusion
>   around what is, and isn't, Ubuntu. **Using the trademarks in your
>   discussion, commentary, criticism or parody, in ways that
>   unequivocally do not imply endorsement, is permissible.** ***Anyone is free
>   to write articles, create websites, blog about, or talk about Ubuntu -
>   as long as it's clear to everyone (including people completely
>   unfamiliar with Ubuntu) that they are simply referring to Ubuntu and
>   in no way speaking for Canonical or the Ubuntu project.***
>
> We reserve the right to review all usage within the open source
>   community, and to object to any usage that appears to overstep the
>   bounds of discussion and good-faith non-commercial development. In any
>   event, once a project has left the open source project phase or
>   otherwise become a commercial project, this policy does not authorise
>   any use of the Trademarks in connection to that project.

Which is enough for me.